# Cannot start test validator - error failed to create ledger

Tags: solana-test-validator

Running into an error trying to start test validator.  Please advise. Thanks.

I'm on MacOS
➜  test-ledger solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.4 (src:356c6a38; feat:3352961542, client:SolanaLabs)

```
> dev solana-test-validator
> 
> Notice! No wallet available. `solana airdrop` localnet SOL after
> creating one
> 
> Ledger location: test-ledger Log: test-ledger/validator.log Error:
> failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io
> error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra
> entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular
```

> test-ledger cat validator.log [2024-03-19T17:41:29.778729000Z INFO
> solana_test_validator] solana-validator 1.18.4 (src:356c6a38;
> feat:3352961542, client:SolanaLabs) [2024-03-19T17:41:29.778814000Z
> INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
> inner: [
> "solana-test-validator",
> ],
> } [2024-03-19T17:41:29.779331000Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled [2024-03-19T17:41:29.782619000Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX
> detected [2024-03-19T17:41:29.782646000Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2
> detected [2024-03-19T17:41:29.788591000Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet]
> Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
> [2024-03-19T17:41:29.788626000Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet
> account address: 6cVS8zWDwSJLe3rPtjZ7mEDBg6CrTBJCkP2WoZcxzmdc
> [2024-03-19T17:41:29.790665000Z INFO
> solana_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
> [2024-03-19T17:41:29.801980000Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Feature
> for 41tVp5qR1XwWRt5WifvtSQyuxtqQWJgEK8w91AtBqSwP deactivated
> [2024-03-19T17:41:29.806696000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore]
> Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000 [2024-03-19T17:41:29.807024000Z
> INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore at
> "test-ledger/rocksdb" [2024-03-19T17:41:29.808865000Z WARN
> solana_ledger::blockstore_db] Unable to detect Rocks columns: Error {
> message: "IO error: No such file or directory: While opening a file
> for sequentially reading: test-ledger/rocksdb/CURRENT: No such file or
> directory" } [2024-03-19T17:41:30.156007000Z INFO
> solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore done; blockstore open
> took 348ms [2024-03-19T17:41:30.172403000Z INFO
> solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not
> found [2024-03-19T17:41:30.172638000Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics]
> datapoint: shred_insert_is_full total_time_ms=0i slot=0i last_index=3i
> num_repaired=0i num_recovered=0i [2024-03-19T17:41:30.308798000Z INFO
> solana_accounts_db::hardened_unpack] Extracting
> "test-ledger/genesis.tar.bz2"...

Answer (score 0):

The error message of:

```
Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin"
```

Leads me to believe that there's something extraneous or wrong in your `test-ledger/`. It might be easiest to delete the whole `test-ledger/` directory, which should be found in the directory from which you're executing the command.

Another possible source of the error is that the user executing the command might not have privileges to create files, so be sure that you can create files and directories from the directory in which you're running `solana-test-validator`.